# Can a Java Applet Access Local File System

Tags: java, jar, applet, appletviewer

I am creating a java applet, that gets information out of a JAR file on my local file system, and creates a jpanel to display in the applet.

I am getting the applet to load correctly on the appletViewer in Eclipse, but it will not load whenever i launch the Html file i created.

The html file is points to the class files, also to the external jars.

Any Suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: This will not be workable for an applet on the internet.  Why on earth would you not simply add the Jar to the `archive` attribute of the applet?  BTW - *"Why does is load in Eclipse but not the web browser though?"* Because Eclipse, typical of IDEs, will run applets with no security sand-box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if the applet is signed with the jarsigner tool.

Comment: Why does is load in Eclipse but not the web browser though?

Answer (score 0):

Unless explicitly granted, an applet may not access the local file system.

"Will not load" sounds like you have a packaging error instead of a permission error.  Have a look at the appletviewer logs.

Comment: i have a policy file that i grant all permissions to, shouldnt that enable me to access anything i want?

Comment: I do not believe policy files allow applets outside the sandbox.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen They do. You can allocate all permissions to a codebase. The local filesystem may be different.

Comment: You need to do so explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Netbeans then right click on your Applet project ->Properties->webstart->
clickon Enablewebstart ->customize->select radio self-signedby generatedkey->ok

then your job will be done